# Put user input of a list of numbers into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering the best way to get a bunch of numbers input by the user seperated by spaces into an array.

For example:
The user would input `0 8 4 12 2 10 6 14 1 9 5 13 3 11 7 15`

and java would put it into an array with each number being its own element in the array.

Thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that that input was already stored in a string called **input**:

```
String[] numbers = input.split(" ");
```

This would give you an array called numbers where

```
String first = numbers[0]; //0 
String second = numbers[1]; //8 
String third = numbers[2]; //4
```

...

Comment: This is awesome, I just have one problem.  It doesn't seem to like the `input.split(" ")`

If i use `input.split("-")` and the numbers are separated by a dash instead of a space it works.  Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind!  Figured it out!  Originally, I had `String input = scan.next();`  but I needed `String input = scan.nextLine();`